# Скрипт с glow-анимацией для IE не работает в Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Не работает скрипт в Firefox. В IE без проблем.

```
<script language=JavaScript>
if (document.all) {
    colours = new Array('ff0000', '00ff00', '3366ff', 'ff00ff', 'ffa500', 'ffffff', 'fff000')
    amount = colours.length;
    YgetDelay = 0, XgetDelay = 0, Ydelay = 0, Xdelay = 0, step = 0.2, currStep = 0, my = 0, mx = 0; //osw
    document.write('<div id="ie" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"><div style="position:relative">');
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    document.write('<div id="iestars" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;height:50px;width:50px;font-family:Courier New;font-size:5px;color:' + colours[i] + ';padding-top:20px;text-align:center">.</div>');
    document.write('</div></div>');
    ini = 1; <!--
    fantasyflash.ru -->
    gstep = 1;

    function iMouse() {
        my = event.y;
        mx = event.x;
    }
    document.onmousemove = iMouse

    function dim() {
        ini -= gstep;
        dt = setTimeout('dim()', 10);
        if (ini < 2) {
            clearTimeout(dt);
            glow();
        }
    }

    function glow() {
        ini += gstep;
        gt = setTimeout('glow()', 10);
        if (ini > 14) {
            clearTimeout(gt);
            dim();
        }
    }

    function stars() {
        ie.style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
        for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            var layer = iestars[i].style;
            layer.filter = 'glow(color=' + colours[i] + ', strength=' + ini + ')';
            layer.top = Ydelay + 100 * Math.sin((5 * Math.sin((currStep - 15.99) / 10)) + i * 70) * Math.sin((currStep) / 10) * Math.cos((currStep + i * 25) / 10);
            layer.left = Xdelay + 180 * Math.cos((5 * Math.sin((currStep - 15.99) / 10)) + i * 70) * Math.sin((currStep) / 10) * Math.cos((currStep + i * 25) / 10);
        }
        currStep += step;
    }

    function delay() {
        Ydelay = YgetDelay += (my - YgetDelay) * 1 / 20;
        Xdelay = XgetDelay += (mx - XgetDelay) * 1 / 20;
        stars(); //osw
        setTimeout('delay()', 10);
    }
    delay();
    glow();
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Для начала оформите скрипт. Думаю врятли кто будет разбираться с этим набором строк.

Answer (score 1):

> Ydelay+100Math.sin((5
> Сомневаюсь, что это у Вас работает в ИЕ. может **100*Math.sin** У Вас таких проблем еще много

Вся проблема в коде **layer.filter='glow(c...** Дело в том, что фильтр GLOW понимает только ИЕ.

Comment: в ИЕ работает 100%

Comment: поищите в интернет плагин jquery, который делает свечение вокруг элементов